# How to properly select document via populate from another document with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I did a select with populate and it works, but feel like there is a better way.

My models:

```js
const DeviceSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  MAC: {type: String, unique: true, required: true, dropUps: true},
  serialNumber: {type: String, unique: true, dropUps: true},
  date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
})


const UserSchema = new Schema({
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
})


const OrganisationSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  members: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
  devices: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Device'}],
  created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
})
```

`User`s and `Device`s may belong to multiple `Organisation`s.
Through `Organisation` the `User` may obtain access to the `Device`s.

The code I seek to optimize:

```js
const devicesSerial = await Organisation.find()
  .where('members')
  .equals(req.user.id)
  .populate('devices', 'MAC')
  .then((orgs) => {
    console.log('orgs', orgs)
    return _.flatMap(
      orgs.map((org) => org.devices.map((device) => device.MAC))
    )
  })

const events = await SensorEvent.aggregate([
  {$match: {MAC: {$in: devicesSerial}}},
  {$sort: {date: 1}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$MAC',
      temperature: {$last: '$temperature'},
      humidity: {$last: '$humidity'},
      weight: {$last: '$weight'},
      theId: {$last: '$_id'},
      date: {$last: '$date'},
    },
  },
])
```

Comment: So does this work as expected? And you're looking for help on improving it?

Comment: @MattOestreich, yes it works, but this looks a bit hasty to me, and I think there should be a better way (i.e. more complex select `aggregate` chain or something like this.